# How do I get HTML5 Video to scrub in chrome when delivered via a service?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, html5-video, seek

So due to content being on a different drive than my server application's virtual directory, I've had to implement a file getting service.

I am able to the get the file size. Then I want to set the content headers so that the browser knows the total size and thus knows how to proportion the seek bar.

Here I set the total size header:

```
   string bytes = Convert.ToString( fInfo.Length );                   
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes );
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", "bytes 0-" + bytes + "/" + bytes);
```

Resulting in:

```
Content-Length: 1389363
Content-Type: video/ogg
Content-Range: bytes 0-1389363/1389364
```

I downloaded the resulting file and confirmed that the bytes match. Works fine in Firefox, all wacky in chrome. **In chrome it plays to the end, but does not move the seek bar and then shows negative infinity in the current time when it reaches the end. ALSO I cannot scrub the video at all, presumably because it has an invalid duration.**

playing the same file directly in chrome works properly, so maybe it's some content header that chrome wants that firefox don't give a s#%t about?

Any ideas? Wrong length unit? built-in server side g-zip encoding interfering?

I'm using standard video object:

```
<video class="videoplayer" controls="" autoplay="autoplay" tabindex="0">
<source type="video/ogg" src="http://vb_html.dev/GetFile.aspx?filename=c:/_assets/4c2c09c2-f2ff-e011-a992-009056af18ff/softsignage/softsignage-00000000600.ogv"></source>
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

For more reference this is how I'm passing the file data:

```
  FileStream mystream = new FileStream(anyFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(mystream))
                    {

                        while (true)
                        {
                            int bytesRead = mystream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            if (bytesRead == 0) break;
                            Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: It seems that I should be using Response.WriteFile() but all the solutions seems pretty complex just to do range specific request handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to get the request range in bytes, and return that portion of the file. You can do this in MVC with

```
     RangeFileStreamResult(Stream fileStream, string contentType, string fileName, DateTime modificationDate);
```

Using the Codeplex example  found in this library http://mvcresumingactions.codeplex.com/

--

Answer (score 1):

Try setting status code to 206:

```
response.StatusCode = 206;
```